# Term for different pronunciations of the same word

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, accent

Does anyone know what it's called when a word's pronunciation changes based on context? I am not talking about different people pronouncing the same word differently (i.e. caramel).

E.g. I say "I am doing REE-search." v.s. when I say "implications for further ruh-SEarch" (or reh-search).

I also would NEVER dream to switch them, as that sounds totally wrong to me.

Can anyone offer other words like this? Does anyone know what this phenomenon is called?

Comment: Funny I pronounce it RE-search no matter the context. I'd pronounce it that way in both your examples. But I do have a friend who alternates between "AFternoon" and "afterNOON"; she says it's to make the cadence of the word "fit" with the rest of the sentence. I can't remember the examples she gave.

Comment: I linked this to [part of speech  pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/239164/191178) but I think it's actually just a dialect thing. Let me see if I can find another question that addresses that.

Comment: _Research_, in the context of schools, has undergone a new burst of change since English became a world language. It now exists in many Englishes as a count noun. I don't know how many times I've heard or read _I'm doing a research on..._ from a student who's been taught to use it in a different context. In my English, _research_ is strictly mass, so you hafta say _I'm doing some research on ..._ And many Americans stress the first syllable of the verb and the second syllable of the noun. But many don't, too.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591137/upset-different-stress-pattern-for-attributive-and-predicative-use) about different pronunciations of "upset" might be relevant. It's hard to name a phenomenon until we know exactly what it is.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, we do hear "a research". However, I only hear it from non-English speakers so I ignore it and wince.

Comment: Why wince? Be a sociolinguist and record it. BTW, here's a (presumably optimal, given the source, but certainly not complete) [list of English two-syllable words with verb/noun stress differences](https://optimacomm.com/services/contrasting-noun-verb-stress/). Note they don't tell you everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler Lambie Yes, *love* it!

Comment: Woah! That's weird. I think I maybe do the same. I don't think it's 'stress shift' in the normally described pattern, but it's certainly a stress shift of some sort.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!! Fascinating answers. Thanks to you I have now found two others: 'upset and up'set and 'concrete and con'crete. So interesting.